# find the newest record for each item from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am monitoring certain information about a list of items. the information comes in regularly however it isn't always valid. I have a formula that tells me whether the information is valid.
the data is structured in the following way.

```
The item List| the info on AB|the info onCD|The DATEValidity info AB|Validity info CD|

ITEM001 | DATA001 |   DATA02 |  DATE1  | Yes Valid         | Not Valid         |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ITEM001 | DATA003 |   DATA04 |  DATE2  | NOT Valid         | YES Valid         | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ITEM002 | DATA005 |   DATA06 |  DATE3  | NOT Valid         | Not Valid         | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ITEM001 | DATA007 |   DATA08 |  DATE4  | YES Valid         | YES Valid         |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ITEM002 | DATA009 |   DATA10 |  DATE5  | YES Valid         | Not Valid         |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ITEM005 | DATA011 |   DATA12 |  DATE6  | NOT Valid         | YES Valid         |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ITEM003 | DATA013 |   DATA14 |  DATE7  | YES Valid         | Not Valid         |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like an easy way for me to arrange the table so that I can find out for each item the last Valid Info1 with its date and the last Valid info2 with its date.

My company has a policy against saving VBA files, so unless this it is absolutely necessary I would like to be able to do this using only formulas.

Comment: When you say `AB` what does it mean? Merged Cell? Anyway I think this is possible using formulas. Btw, your date is arranged? It will be easier if it is arranged (e.g. descending or ascending).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this with or without sorting the dates:

I assumed that your data looks like this:
[image: Sample Data]

In `Cell H2` use this formula:

`=INDEX(B$1:B$7,MATCH(MAX(IF(E$1:E$7="Yes Valid",D$1:D$7)),D$1:D$7,0))`

In `Cell I2` use this formula:

`=INDEX(D$1:D$7,MATCH(MAX(IF(E$1:E$7="Yes Valid",D$1:D$7)),D$1:D$7,0))`

In `Cell H5` use this formula:

`=INDEX(C$1:C$7,MATCH(MAX(IF(F$1:F$7="Yes Valid",D$1:D$7)),D$1:D$7,0))`

In `Cell I5` use this formula:

`=INDEX(D$1:D$7,MATCH(MAX(IF(F$1:F$7="Yes Valid",D$1:D$7)),D$1:D$7,0))`

Above are all `Array Formulas` entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Excellent, It never occurred to me I could use a function inside match index. thanks a lot. this really helps